# Twitter API from

Tags: api, twitter

I have created a page on my site where users can post directly to their twitter accounts using a form on my site. I am using curl to send the data. However, when they post something it says it was posted "from API" I would like to change that to my sitename/link. I read something about doing it through OAUTH but I do not want my users to have to leave my site and go to twitter. I just want to show my site there. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link might help you a bit 
http://www.sakana.fr/blog/2007/03/18/scripting-twitter-with-curl/

And for changing the client shown, pass the source variable, something like this should work:

```
curl --basic --user username:password --data status="Having fun with cURL" http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml?source=MySuperClient
```

Comment: I think you meant source variable in the query string?

Comment: I tried passing the source with the request but now instead of saying from API it says from web. Any ideas?

Comment: If you check out the "More Information" in my answer, you will see that twitter no longer allows custom client names without Oauth, and you have to register a custom name anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to use Oauth, the original method was discontinued. Before that, though, you have to register your application here: [New Client](http://twitter.com/oauth_clients/new).

More information: [Here](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/FAQ#HowdoIget%E2%80%9CfromMyApp%E2%80%9DappendedtoupdatessentfrommyAPIapplication)

Comment: obviously you cant read since I said I dont want to use oauth because I dont want users to have to leave my site.

Comment: I dont know how to implement oauth to make it so users dont have to leave my site.

Comment: Unfortunatly, Oauth is your only choice if you want a custom name.